# Accessing Array Object property in ES6,

Tags: javascript, arrays, redux, ecmascript-6, react-redux

my friend, I hope you are all fine over there. Please, I would like to know how I can access some specific value within an array object! I am designing an app with Redux, and I was able to retrieve the first array object value but the last array object which is more complex than the previous is giving headache. Can someone help me out. Below is the Object:

```js
{
    [
        [{
            "id": 1,
            "full_name": "jack",
            "email": "carl@gmail.com",
            "phone": "2123309",
            "dob": "2008-06-12",
            "location": "VAUGHAN",
            "user_id": 1,
            "created_at": "2021-10-02T09:10:04.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-10-02T12:16:57.000000Z"
        }],
        [{
            "id": 1,
            "price": "432.00",
            "order_type": "Car Parking",
            "currency": "USD",
            "paid": 0,
            "amount_paid": "432.00",
            "overdue": "0.00",
            "client_id": 1,
            "user_id": 1,
            "created_at": "2021-10-02T09:10:26.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-10-02T09:46:00.000000Z"
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "price": "2500.00",
            "order_type": "Ramp",
            "currency": "USD",
            "paid": 0,
            "amount_paid": "2030.00",
            "overdue": "470.00",
            "client_id": 1,
            "user_id": 1,
            "created_at": "2021-10-02T09:48:07.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-10-02T10:14:22.000000Z"
        }, {
            "id": 9,
            "price": "893.00",
            "order_type": "Shipping",
            "currency": "CAD",
            "paid": 0,
            "amount_paid": "765.00",
            "overdue": "128.00",
            "client_id": 1,
            "user_id": 1,
            "created_at": "2021-10-02T10:46:45.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-10-02T10:54:06.000000Z"
        }, {
            "id": 21,
            "price": "250.00",
            "order_type": "Storage rent",
            "currency": "USD",
            "paid": 0,
            "amount_paid": "0.00",
            "overdue": "250.00",
            "client_id": 1,
            "user_id": 1,
            "created_at": "2021-10-03T08:33:13.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-10-03T08:33:13.000000Z"
        }]
    ]
}
```

To access FULL_NAME I did :

```js
client.data.map((client) => client[0].full_name)
```

if I try to access a second array with [1] it gives me cannot access that property.

Now there are two things I wish to do here, get the length of the second array, and be able to loop over that array. Also, how can I access a specific value in that object, let assume for instance I want to retrieve AMOUNT_PAID in object 2. Any idea please?

Comment: What is the expected result? What exactly is `client.data`? I don’t see anything specific to [tag:react-redux] in the question.

Comment: The provided json is not valid

Comment: @ziishaned It’s valid, but not JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `map` over the array at index `[1]`, and use `.length` to get the length of the outcome array.

```js
const data = [
  [{
    "id": 1,
    "full_name": "jack",
    "email": "carl@gmail.com",
    "phone": "2123309",
    "dob": "2008-06-12",
    "location": "VAUGHAN",
    "user_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2021-10-02T09:10:04.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-10-02T12:16:57.000000Z"
  }],
  [{
    "id": 1,
    "price": "432.00",
    "order_type": "Car Parking",
    "currency": "USD",
    "paid": 0,
    "amount_paid": "432.00",
    "overdue": "0.00",
    "client_id": 1,
    "user_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2021-10-02T09:10:26.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-10-02T09:46:00.000000Z"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "price": "2500.00",
    "order_type": "Ramp",
    "currency": "USD",
    "paid": 0,
    "amount_paid": "2030.00",
    "overdue": "470.00",
    "client_id": 1,
    "user_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2021-10-02T09:48:07.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-10-02T10:14:22.000000Z"
  }, {
    "id": 9,
    "price": "893.00",
    "order_type": "Shipping",
    "currency": "CAD",
    "paid": 0,
    "amount_paid": "765.00",
    "overdue": "128.00",
    "client_id": 1,
    "user_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2021-10-02T10:46:45.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-10-02T10:54:06.000000Z"
  }, {
    "id": 21,
    "price": "250.00",
    "order_type": "Storage rent",
    "currency": "USD",
    "paid": 0,
    "amount_paid": "0.00",
    "overdue": "250.00",
    "client_id": 1,
    "user_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2021-10-03T08:33:13.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-10-03T08:33:13.000000Z"
  }]
]

const result = data[1].map(x => x.amount_paid);
const resultLength = result.length;

console.log("Result: ", result);
console.log("Length: ", resultLength);
```

Comment: saying property .length undefinded

Comment: You are probably calling `.length` on an object (which it sees as a property that is not defined), you should call it on the array.

Comment: @chablis18 is it working?

Comment: As it was so tricky, I  therefore changed the logic. But I will check for it and let you know

Comment: @chablis18 Do you have an update on your work?

Comment: yeah but i am having another issue i wish help to solve it. I will create another threads so that you can see it